# Using javascript function in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a jquery app which includes javascript functions which in turn calls another javascript function.

I am facing 2 problems:

1. If the html file is in a folder and the javascript file is in another folder, I can't call it.
2. I am having a problem sending the arguments to the functions in the javascript file "even if the javascript file and html file are in the same folder".

This is the curent code:

html file:
[image: html file]

[image: javascript file]

errors: 
1:
Uncaught ReferenceError: LOG is not defined(anonymous function) @ sbc_cookies_mon.js:1
4DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:windowIsActivated

2:
Uncaught ReferenceError: dcal is not definedonclick @ couples.html:24

Comment: Could you add some more information? What is the error displayed in the javascript console?

Comment: hey .. it's showing that file not found and when put in same directory it simply doesn't work

Comment: Please don't display your code in screenshots, is better add it in your question.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of the code try to copy paste the code itself

Comment: That error probably means that the path supplied is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools in Chrome or any browser to check if the JavaScript file you are referencing is available or missing.

Next use debugger points in the JavaScript file to check the if code is being executed till that point.

If the function is unable to get the argument check if the ID of the HTML element is correct. You can do this in the debugger console to check if the "document.getElementById('elementid').value" is returning a value or not.

OR

another way would be to get the value of the HTML element inside the JavaScript function "dcal()" instead of passing them as arguments from the html.

Comment: thanks .. I tried that but it didn't work .. and i updated the question with the errors .. thanks again

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle of your code and share the link here so that we could check it.

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepv75/rudy7dhr/)